org.kie.kogito:kogito-quarkus is missing from the current stream, it has been unselected
I'm encountering the following error:
'org.kie.kogito:kogito-quarkus' is missing from the current stream '', it has been unselected.
Can someone help me understand the cause of this error?
Does this mean Quarkus no longer supports Kogito?
Is Kogito no longer supported or maintained?
Why are events related to Kogito not being held anymore?
Why are the YouTube videos, blog, and other media related to Kogito not being updated?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
